# How do you generate text file to store on server in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, web

Just started using Flutter for windows, web, and android, and immediately ran into many blocking problems making a basic report log system.

I need to generate and append a basic text file, stored on the web server end, in a basic folder.

How do I do this, since 'dart:io' Directory is out for web builds?

Comment: This is a server-side problem.  It has nothing to do with Flutter for the web, which runs on the client.  Clients should not be able to write arbitrary files on the server.